# Regex: remove www. from domain name only for domain-strings whit two or more dots

Tags: regex

Have a real domain names like www.by or www.ru, so for such domains I wanna keep "www.".
But for other domains, like [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) or [www.sub.example.org](http://www.sub.example.org) "www." need to be removed.

I have tried regex such `^(www[0-9]*\.)(\.*){2,}` but is not working...
Have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace matches of the following regular expression with empty strings:

```
^www\d*\.(?=.*\.)
```

The *positive lookahead* `(?=.*\.)` asserts that the first period is followed later in the string by another period.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2m0jUS/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
^www[0-9]*\.((?:[^.]*\.)+)
```

Replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rWtYjy/2/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `www[0-9]*\.` - `www`, any zero or more digits, and a `.`
- `((?:[^.]*\.)+)` - Group 1 (`$1` refers to this value from the replacement pattern): one or more occurrences of zero or more chars other than a `.` and then a `.` char.